# Java Matcher Digit method

Tags: java, regex

How can Match Digit Integer from a Strings and return the Integer value.?
e.g;

```
String = "Color Red, Size 32 / Text text";
```

I would like to get from this string that "32" Integer value.

many thanks in advance.

regards,
Koko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Color Red, Size 32 / Text text";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
      String find = matcher.group();
      Integer i = Integer.parseInt(find);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Testing1234Testing");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```